# how to import downloaded code from code.google into Eclipse and auto change package name?

Tags: android

I've downloaded the source code from code.google from android. 
Because they dont come with the eclipse project. I've import them into eclipse.
Assuming i've downloaded ABC source code with package named com.example.abc
1. I can't import via "Existing Projects into Workspace".
2. I tried create a android project named ABC with package com.sample.abc
i tried import via "achive file" or "file system" into created folder abc.
But, all imported files will go into folder abc\abc\src, abc\abc\res,....
3. how to auto change package name accordingly current project package name?
or i've to create project following package name from the downloaded code?

Comment: You could just create a new Android project and simply copy resources into it. Do the copying int OS's file explorer and refresh eclipse project afterwards and then run project-> clean.

Comment: yah, but i tot there could have better way to do it.

Comment: would love how to do this myself as well